# What does it mean when Android studio returns unable to download gradle and also has a cache problem?

Tags: macos, android-studio, gradle

This is one of the error messages and the other ones follow. I only made a empty template of android app nothing crazy. I also wasn't able to run app because of failed gradle. I do have space in my device and not sure why it is bringing up cache. I restarted my cache. I tried what people suggested others on stack overflow so far ,but many of those problems have to deal with one of these problems not all of them and what they did to fix didn't work for me. I also didn't find one that looks like this message below.

*> > Task:app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses

> Failed to execute org.gradle.cache.internal.
>
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: No space left on device Caused by:
> java.io.IOException: No space left on device*

Comment: How much space do you have on your device? Anyway you can try `./gradlew clean` might help. Also try Invalidate Caches & Restart.

Comment: About my computer: iMac 2013

Comment: Processor 3.1 GHz Quad Core Intel Core i7 Memory: 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3

Comment: I use 11.26 GB and have space of 1.12 TB

Comment: Then rebuild project (build --> clean or build --> rebuild) and Invalidate Caches & Restart should help as answered previously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to build > clean project.

And then,

2. Go to File > Invalidate caches & restart.